# non-ordinal access to rows returned by Spark SQL query

Tags: apache-spark

In the Spark documentation, it is stated that the result of a Spark SQL query is a SchemaRDD. Each row of this SchemaRDD can in turn be accessed by ordinal. I am wondering if there is any way to access the columns using the field names of the case class on top of which the SQL query was built. I appreciate the fact that the case class is not associated with the result, especially if I have selected individual columns and/or aliased them: however, some way to access fields by name rather than ordinal would be convenient.

Answer (score 2):

A simple way is to use the "language-integrated" `select` method on the resulting SchemaRDD to select the column(s) you want -- this still gives you a SchemaRDD, and if you select more than one column then you will still need to use ordinals, but you can always select one column at a time. Example:

```
// setup and some data
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
import sqlContext._
case class Score(name: String, value: Int)
val scores = 
  sc.textFile("data.txt").map(_.split(",")).map(s => Score(s(0),s(1).trim.toInt))
scores.registerAsTable("scores")

// initial query
val original = 
  sqlContext.sql("Select value AS myVal, name FROM scores WHERE name = 'foo'")

// now a simple "language-integrated" query -- no registration required 
val secondary = original.select('myVal)
secondary.collect().foreach(println)
```

Now `secondary` is a SchemaRDD with just one column, and it works despite the alias in the original query.

Edit: but note that you **can** register the resulting SchemaRDD and query it with straight SQL syntax without needing another case class.

```
original.registerAsTable("original")
val secondary = sqlContext.sql("select myVal from original")
secondary.collect().foreach(println)
```

Second edit: When processing an RDD one row at a time, it's possible to access the columns by name by using the matching syntax:

```
val secondary = original.map {case Row(myVal: Int, _) => myVal}
```

although this could get cumbersome if the right hand side of the '=>' requires access to a lot of the columns, as they would each need to be matched on the left. (This from a very useful comment in the [source code for the Row companion object](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/Row.scala))

Comment: Thanks, Spiro. However, I really need all/many of the columns, and it's inconvenient to call them individually. Is this a job that is better done as a direct join on the RDDs rather than using Spark SQL?

Comment: @Joe, I think I need some more context on what the code using the results is going to look like. Are you going to be manipulating individual rows? Are there so many columns you're not willing to repack the rows into case classes?

Comment: Spiro, the number of rows is not overwhelming, and right now I am repacking them into case classes. I was just hoping to find some way of accessing by column name (or name_tablealias if column names were identical in multiple tables) as would be possible after a merge in pandas or SQL.

Comment: @Joe: in that case my "second edit" to my answer may not be of any more use to you, but I did want to make sure you noticed it, as I think it's kind of interesting.